# To split 1 String into multiple rows

Tags: talend

I have input file like -

101 | This is split example

I want to this string "This is split example" into multiple rows.

1st 10 rows in 1st row
2nd 10 rows in 2 row and so on

Output file as like -

101 | This is sp
101 | lit exampl
101 | e

Using Talend how to split this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tJavaFlex and something like:

```
   String myString = "This is split example"; //Basically something from outside
   do { 
//this is the main part:
    if(myString.length() > 10) {
       System.out.println(myString.substring(0,10));
       myString = myString.substring(10);
    } else {
      System.out.println(myString);
      myString = "";
    }
//this is the end part
   } while(myString.length() != 0);
```

of course instead of printing you'd like to assign it to an output (row2.data) but you get the idea.

Comment: Okay..
Will check and implement
Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

[image]

tJava

output_row.id = input_row.id;
output_row.StringToSplit= input_row.StringToSplit.replaceAll(".{10}(?!$)", "$0;");

then in tNormalise

Normalise column StringToSplit with separator ;